# Single word for "having a strong desire for revenge"

Tags: single-word-requests

Which words describe the definition "having a strong desire for revenge"?

I found this word somewhere  a few days ago, can't remember where, and I looked it up on Google's dictionary or Siri, and I meant to take note of it, and I forgot about it until now. However, I can't remember what word it was, but I remember the definition.
I tried searching for it using my browser's history, but it doesn't show up.
For example, I want to say, 'my friend is or was, (adjective) or is a(n) (adjective noun).
No, it's not vengeful. It's something else.

Comment: 'Vindictive' appears in the lists given when looking up 'vengeful' at [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/vengeful).

Comment: Pasting the phrase "having a strong desire for revenge" into Google search box gives you "vindictive" in the second result.  (The first result being this ELU post.)

Comment: Any online thesaurus would have helped your search. [Vindictiveness](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=r1jxWpORO8G8sgGigKnAAQ&q=synonyms+revenge&oq=synonyms+revenge&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i10i30k1j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1l2j0i22i30k1l3.3183.7647.0.9616.8.8.0.0.0.0.213.1181.0j7j1.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.8.1179...0i131i67k1j0i67k1j0i131k1.0.Nq4e7zbfYp4) appears as the second synonym of *revenge* whose 2nd meaning is: "the desire to repay an injury or wrong"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Vindictive* fits your criteria. For example, 'my friend is a vindictive person'.

Link for definition: https://www.google.com.au/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/vindictive

Comment: That's exactly the word I was looking for, and I did take note of it. HOw did you manage to find it? Just curious. It's funny how I had it right there, I just forgot that I did it. Also, I remember seeing this word in a Facebook comment yesterday.

Comment: I just read a lot. Especially the older classics with a lot of big words in them. You can't really forget a word when you've seen it used in a dozen different sentences.

Comment: Hello, Archi. Please supply an attributed link giving the definition for your correct answer.